# How to print the list of files in a folder from build logs in make file?

Tags: windows, makefile, build, gnu-make

We are using make utility in windows to build our project. The version of make is "GNU Make 3.81". I need to understand how our project is built and so have added additional log lines like below which is working as expected --

```
$(warning Entering componentsWin32.mak )
```

Additionally I need to find the current directory and the list of files in that directory, for the first one, this is working--

```
$(warning Entering componentsWin32.make $(CURDIR))
```

To print the list of files in a directory I tried this but it did-not work --

```
$(warning Entering componentsWin32.make $(DIR))
```

Is it possible using $(SHELL...some command) or any other way? Any pointers to this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `$(wildcard [path string])` will evaluate to a list of files which are desginated by `path string`: the path string may be written as a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), so e.g.

```
$(wildcard $(CURDIR)/src/*.c)
```

will evaluate to a list of all C files, given that there is a subdirectory `src` under your current directory with `*.c` files in it.
You can even pass an arbitrary number of such path expressions:

```
$(wildcard $(CURDIR)/src/*.c $(MY_INCLUDE_DIR)/*.h)
```

Obviously, spaces in path names are not allowed.